# Use shinyjs onlick command to toggle an image

Tags: r, shiny, onclick, shinyjs

i'm trying to incorporate shinyjs::onclick() to toggle a picture within my shiny app. 
For some reason - this this not work.

If I use a regular observeEven and "`toggle`" everything is fine and it works.
This tells me that `useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)` command is working.

````
```{r}
actionButton("do", "TRANSFORM")
```

```{r}
    plotOutput("plot3")

    observeEvent(input$do, {
    toggle("plot3", anim = TRUE)
    })

    output$plot3 <- renderImage({

      filename <- normalizePath(file.path('./cover2.png'))

      list(src = filename)
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)
```
````

On the other hand if I try using instead of `ObserveEvent`:

```
onclick("do",  toggle("plot3"))
```

Nothing happens.
I read many examples on the internet and these should be pretty simple... or not? :)

Note: I'm using `RMarkdown` with `runtime:shiny`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [runtime: shiny_prerendered](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.html), this works:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "2 juillet 2019"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(shinyjs)
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)
```

```{r}
actionButton("do", "TRANSFORM")
plotOutput("plot3")
```

```{r, context = "server"}
onclick("do", toggle("plot3", anim = TRUE)) 

output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
  plot(0,0)
})
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is strange - I copy and paste your code and it does not work :( I updated to R3.6, updated to latest RStudio version and updated my Java Runtime...

Comment: When I changed where the library and UseShinyjs are loaded to {r setup, context="server"} it worked somehow. Still do not understand what the issue exactly is...